# calendar without search bar

Tags: lightning, calendar

[image]I was trying to bring Salesforce OOTB lightning calendar under one tab without search event and more option bar. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't. That's the global search bar. It's on all pages. I assume you might find a way to add a custom lightning component that could "hide" it, but I wouldn't recommend it.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/global-header/

[image]